# How to pass Array to IFrame Element in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, iframe

i need to pass an array to iframe window in vue. Before this, I managed to pass data to iFrame base on an answer in stackoverflow but the solution won't work for Array. Here's how i tried:

Vue Last Try:

`<iframe :src="getMultipleMarkers"></iframe>`

```
    getMultipleMarkers(){
        var markers = [this.reports];
        console.log(markers )
        return `http://127.0.0.1:8000/multipleMarakers.html?reports=${markers}`;
    },
```

I can pass value of 1 index of array like this`markers[0][x]['created_at']`. but i need whole array

Vue First Trye:

```
    getMultipleMarkers(){
        return `http://127.0.0.1:8000/multipleMarakers.html?reports=${this.reports}`;
    },
```

I passed all my data from like this method from above code but they wasn't array. passed data was like `${this.customData} => which customData had a string text`.

And here's how i got data from vue in iFrame:

```
var params = location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
data = {};
for (x in params)
{
    data[params[x].split('=')[0]] = params[x].split('=')[1];
}
console.log(data['reports']);
```

And the result for above code in console is like :

`[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]`

which `[object%20Object]` are repeated base on array length. How can i pass my `reports` to iFrame element?

Edit 01 : Result of Mathew Berg's Solution

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 3`

Console Log of markers :

[image]

I removed Stringify in html file and this was results :

[image]

Looks like these characters with %22 are adding in results with no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to JSON.stringify it before hand:

```
 getMultipleMarkers() {
    var markers = [this.reports];
    console.log(markers)
    return `http://127.0.0.1:8000/multipleMarakers.html?reports=${JSON.stringify(markers)}`;
 },
```

And then parse it when you get it:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data['reports']));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've got error, I've updated my question base on your solution with error and console log image.

Comment: Did you do the first part where there's the `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: Yes. just like what u typed.

Comment: Any idea my friend?

Comment: Your answer was correct but I've got another problem, which i will create a new topic for it.